# Hide elements when a clickable event occur on a specific id between multiple ones

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**HTML EDIT**

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
<input class="img1" type="image" style="width:60px;height:60px" 

src="../images/molar_left_t.png" id="oone" name="one" alt="button"/><div id="div_one" class="collapse">3rd Molar: <?php echo $resTeeth['one'] ?></div>
<input class="img1" type="image" style="width:60px;height:60px" src="../images/molar_left_t.png" id="otwo" name="two" alt="button"/><div id="div_two" class="collapse"><?php echo $resTeeth['two'] ?></div>
<input class="img1" type="image" style="width:60px;height:60px" src="../images/molar_left_t.png" id="othree" name="three" alt="button"/><div id="div_three" class="collapse"><?php echo $resTeeth['three'] ?></div>
 <input class="img1" type="image" style="width:60px;height:60px" src="../images/bicuspid_2_left_t.png" id="ofour" name="four" alt="button"/><div id="div_four" class="collapse"><?php echo $resTeeth['four'] ?></div>
 <input class="img1" type="image" style="width:60px;height:60px" src="../images/bicuspid_1_left_t.png" id="ofive" name="five" alt="button"/><div id="div_five" class="collapse"><?php echo $resTeeth['five'] ?></div>
```

I have this script that helps me to collapse a div that it is after the clicked image:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("#oone, #otwo, #othree, #ofour, #ofive, #osix, #oseven, #oeight, #onine, #oten, #otwelve, #otwenty, #othirteen, #ofourteen, #ofifteen, #osixteen, #loone, #lotwo, #lothree, #lofour, #lofive, #losix, #loseven, #loeight, #lonine, #laaten, #lotwelve, #lotwenty, #lothirteen, #lofourteen, #lofifteen, #losixteen").click(function()
  {
    $(this).css('border', "solid 2px red");
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
  });
});
```

Now, I need to hide all the other unclicked images. I.e.: if I clicked on button with an  id of `#oone`, the next element will `slideToggle()`, I need the others to be hidden until I click on the same element to collapse, so they will be visible again

Answer (score 0):

You can use `siblings()`

```
$(this).siblings().slideToggle();
```

Comment: Okay, but when I click on the same button again, those who disappeared, didn't show again

Answer (score 0):

Use `.siblings()` find the elements which comes under the same parent.

**Working Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".img1").click(function() {
    var curElem = $(this)
    if (!$(this).hasClass('hidden')) {

      $(this).addClass('hidden');
      $(this).next().slideToggle()
      $(this).siblings().hide();
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass('hidden');
      $(this).next().slideToggle()
      $(this).siblings().show();
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.hidden {
  border: solid 2px red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
  <input class="img1" type="image" style="width:60px;height:60px" src="../images/molar_left_t.png" id="oone" name="one" alt="button" />
  <div id="div_one" class="collapse">3rd Molar:
    <?php echo $resTeeth[ 'one'] ?>
  </div>
  <input class="img1" type="image" style="width:60px;height:60px" src="../images/molar_left_t.png" id="otwo" name="two" alt="button" />
  <div id="div_two" class="collapse">
    <?php echo $resTeeth[ 'two'] ?>
  </div>
  <input class="img1" type="image" style="width:60px;height:60px" src="../images/molar_left_t.png" id="othree" name="three" alt="button" />
  <div id="div_three" class="collapse">
    <?php echo $resTeeth[ 'three'] ?>
  </div>
  <input class="img1" type="image" style="width:60px;height:60px" src="../images/bicuspid_2_left_t.png" id="ofour" name="four" alt="button" />
  <div id="div_four" class="collapse">
    <?php echo $resTeeth[ 'four'] ?>
  </div>
  <input class="img1" type="image" style="width:60px;height:60px" src="../images/bicuspid_1_left_t.png" id="ofive" name="five" alt="button" />
  <div id="div_five" class="collapse">
    <?php echo $resTeeth[ 'five'] ?>
  </div>

  <!--31 one more similar input images-->

</div>
```

Comment: nope. The others does not appear again when I click on the same button

Comment: Is your requirement met in the demo?

Comment: yeah. Exactly. But I don't know why it didn't worked with me

Comment: `:)` dont forget to add the class `img` as said in previous question

Comment: I did it the same as you asked

Comment: It will be great if you can include the `HTML` also

Comment: Okay I will added. Remeber that I need to only slideToggle the div that is near the clicked image, and the other (images and divs) need to be hidden. And then when I click again on the same button, I need to get back all the elements in the page back as their is

Comment: see the edit now please. Remeber that I need to only slideToggle the div that is near the clicked image, and the other (images and divs) need to be hidden. And then when I click again on the same button, I need to get back all the elements in the page back as their is

Comment: can you return the previous script of the demo ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this might give you a start here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.form-group').on('click','.img1',function() {
    $(this).css('border', "solid 2px red");
    $(this).next('.collapse').slideToggle();
    $(this).siblings('.img1').toggle();
  });
});
```

**EDIT:** Note change `.toggle()` to `.slideToggle()` if you desire that effect everywhere.

Not 100% sure on the other div's what you require but for the images should work.

Try it out here:https://jsfiddle.net/2y98yddj/

IF you also want to hide the other div's you could add that with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.form-group') .on('click','.img1',function() {
    $(this).css('border', "solid 2px red");
    $(this).next('.collapse').slideToggle().siblings('.collapse').toggle();
    $(this).siblings('.img1').toggle();
  });
});
```

Note as a one-liner and also fix the "other" images border CSS do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.form-group').on('click', '.img1', function() {
    $(this).css('border', "solid 2px red")
      .siblings('.img1').slideToggle().css('border', "none").end()
      .siblings('.collapse').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

As I indicated, this should get you started here.